# Delete specified path file and display msgbox if no file

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete the files in the specified directory with asking  MsgBoxStyle.YesNo and display a msgbox if these files don't exist.

I tried the following code but only MsgBoxStyle.YesNo opens, nothing else happens.

```
    Dim di As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\1.txt")
    Dim di1 As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\2.txt")
    Dim di2 As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\3.txt")

    If MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    ElseIf di.Exists And di1.Exists And di2.Exists Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\1.txt")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\2.txt")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\3.txt")
        MsgBox("Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        MsgBox("No file found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End If
```

I also tried the following code. But this time if file does not exist, the app crashes.

```
Dim di As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\1.txt")
Dim di1 As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\2.txt")
Dim di2 As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\3.txt")

If di.Exists And di1.Exists And di2.Exists Then
ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\1.txt")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\2.txt")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\3.txt")
    MsgBox("Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
Else
    MsgBox("No file found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
End If
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating `DirectoryInfo` objects with file paths? It should be obvious that a `DirectoryInfo` represents a directory, also know as a folder, while a `FileInfo` object represents a file. Create a `FileInfo` object to represent a file and call its `Delete` method to delete that file.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that, I'm still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in both solutions, you wrongly use'ElseIf'.corrct way to do it:

1. solution 1:

   ```
   If MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
       If di.Exists And di1.Exists And di2.Exists Then
           My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\1.txt")
           My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\2.txt")
           My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\3.txt")
           MsgBox("Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
       Else
           MsgBox("No file found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
       End If
   End If
   ```
2. solution 2:

   ```
     If di.Exists And di1.Exists And di2.Exists Then
       If MsgBox("Are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

           My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\1.txt")
           My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\2.txt")
           My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\..\..\3.txt")
           MsgBox("Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
       Else
           MsgBox("No file found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
   End If
   ```